# Cannot await "ProjectName.Models.Class"

Tags: c#, async-await

I am attempting to retrieve some data from a database using DTO. I'm following a guide example in class but for some reason it doesn't await for my class. Here's the piece of code.

```
// GET api/Orders/5
[ResponseType(typeof(OrderDetailDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrder(int id)
{
    var order = await db.Orders.Include(o =>o.drug).
    Include(o=>o.patient).Include(o => o.doctor).Select(o => new OrderDetailDTO()
    {
        Id = o.Id,
        instruction = o.instruction,
        quantity = o.quantity,
        totalPrice = o.totalPrice,
        patientName = o.patient.name,
        doctorName = o.doctor.name,
        drugName = o.drug.drugName

    }).SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
    if(order == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(order);
}
```

Any idea?

Some things to add: In the example, I'm supposed to end it with:

```
}).SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id);
```

But it only allows SingleOrDefault. I've double checked my using fields but nothing was particularly wrong.

EDIT: Thanks for the response! I've solved my issue.

I've learnt that I need to use the SingleOrDefaultAsync to return an awaitable object. And the SingleOrDefaultAsync requires EF6.

Comment: **it doesn't await for my class** .. what is happening?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? I think you need EF6 for async.

Comment: Ah, mine's 5. According to the Nuget package manager under intsalled packages.

Comment: Installed 6, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you cannot await `db….SingleOrDefault(…)`. `SingleOrDefault` is synchronous and returns an actual non-Task object.

You need to use `SingleOrDefaultAsync(…)` here in order to be able to await it.

Why you can’t use that is another problem, but it’s the one you should be asking yourself. Do you have the necessary imports for it? E.g. `System.Data.Entity`?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I have.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using DoctorOrderService.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

Comment: If its for SingleOrDefaultAsync:
'System.Linq.IQueryable<DoctorOrderService.Models.OrderDetailDTO' does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefaultAsync and no extension method 'SingleOrDefaultAsyn' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DoctorOrderService.Models.OrderDetailDTO' 
could be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: If it for the await, then: 

struct System.Void
Specifies a return value type for a method that does not return a value

Cannot await 'DoctorOrderService.Models.OrderDetailDTO